# "write_timeout" not working in Serial() in pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to make a program which constantly reads data being sent from device using serial port to computer. In addition to this whenever I enter something it is sent to device.(My main aim is to make a serial terminal emulator).
I wrote following program but it waits for any input and does not constantly read data and display on screen sent by device as thought:

```
ser1 = serial.Serial(com_name_to_use, auto_baud, timeout=0, write_timeout=0)
while True:
    try:
        # Writing Section
        inp_str1 = input()  # + "\n"
        str1 = inp_str1.encode(encoding="ascii")
        ser1.write(str1)
        time.sleep(0.03)
        # Reading Section
        bf = ser1.readline()
        print(str(bf, encoding="utf-8"), end="")
    except Exception as err1:
        pass
```

Kindly, tell how to fix it.

Comment: The first thing to do is to print out any exceptions that might be occuring. Add `print(err1)` in the exception handler. You should not blindly ignore exceptions in this way. Then add some `print()` calls before and after the I/O operations so you can see what the program is doing. Also, `write()` returns the number of bytes written, so bind that to a variable and print it out.

Comment: You neglect to describe how the program does behave even though it's not as expected.  *"it waits for any input"* -- A simple sequential program cannot properly handle input from more than one source.  In order to receive from both the *"device"* and operator (keyboard?) input, the typical approach is to use threads, or a syscall such as **select()** or **poll()** that reports when/if input is available.